# How to move cursor to the new line while using whileloop?

Tags: c, while-loop, newline, getchar

This is the code for counting characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    long nc = 0;
    while(getchar() != EOF){
        ++nc;
        printf("%d\n", nc);
    }
}
```

The **output** looks something like this.

```
ab
1
2
3
cd
4
5
6
ef
7
8
9
```

And I want the **output** to look something like this..i.e with added newline after every completion.

```
ab
1
2
3

cd
4
5
6

ef
7
8
9
```

How to do it ??

Comment: You forgot to mention what your test input is.

Comment: I did'nt get it. test input?? Although I guess ab, cd, ef are inputs which are entered while the code is running through getchar(). and following 123, 456, 789 are the output respectively. I'm sorry if I'm getting it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the input character to a variable. Then you can test if it's a newline and print a blank line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    long nc = 0;
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++nc;
        printf("%d\n", nc);
        if (c == '\n') {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @barmar. It is working.